# Smallest element in a list using higher-order functions

Tags: scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

I am trying to find the smallest element in a list of numbers.

This is trivial when using explicit recursion, but I am looking for a way to do this using solely the built-in higher-order functions, like

`map`,

`filter`,

and `foldr`.

In other words, I want to use a combination of these functions to get what I am looking for.

Comment: Not overly familiar with scheme but could you repeatedly filter all elements smaller than the first one in the list until the list size is one?

Answer (score 1):

Use foldr. The accumulator begins as +inf.0. The combine-accumulator-and-element should return the smallest of the accumulator and the element.

Comment: Curious why you recommend foldl instead of foldr? What difference would there be compared to using foldl?

Comment: I just picked the same fold as mentioned in the question. You are right: foldl would be better in this case, since `min` doesn't depend on the order of arguments.

Comment: wups I didn't mean to suggest `foldl` was better. I honestly don't know when it's better to use one over the other when they both result in the same return value

Comment: For small lists it doesn't matter which one is used. If you look at the definitions of `foldl` and `foldr` you will see that the first can begin using the function right away while the other must wait until it reached the end of list before it can use the function "on the way back".

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find the smallest element in a list of numbers.

The obvious way is to use the built-in [min](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._min%29%29)

```
#lang racket

(apply min '(5 2 3 6 4 0 9 -3 2 6))
;; => -3
```

However, if you have to implement your own `min` procedure, [foldl](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) will help you. I also made this procedure throw an error when attempting to use it on an empty list – much like the built-in `min` would do if you tried applying it to zero arguments.

```
#lang racket

(define (min xs)
  (match xs
    ((list x xs ...) (foldl (λ (x acc) (if (< x acc) x acc))
                            x
                            xs))
    (_ (error 'min "must use non-empty list"))))


(min '(5 2 3 6 4 0 9 -3 2 6))
;; => -3

(min '())
;; => min: must use non-empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use 'sort' function on the list and then take first element of the sorted list:

```
(first (sort '(5 2 3 6 4 0 9 -3 2 6) <))
;; => -3
```